# Player de música com playlist

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Eai, galera!

Estou tentando criar um player de música com playlist, porém não estou tendo muito sucesso, pois quando clico em alguma música o player de música abre em outra página e não na página principal onde quero que fique o player e onde quero que toque (como padrão).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês podem me dar uma ajuda nisso?

Tenho esse código:

```js
//* PLAYER DE MÚSICA.
         inicio();
         function inicio(){
             var corrente = 0;
             var audio = $("#musica");
             var playlist = $("#playlist");
             var tracks = playlist.find("li a");
             var len = tracks.length -1;
             musica[0].play();
             playlist.find("a").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 link = $(this);
                 corrente = link.parent().index();
                 run(link, musica[0]);
             });
             musica[0].addEventListener("ended", function(e){
                 corrente++;
                 if(corrente == len){
                     corrente = 0;
                     link = playlist.find("a")[0];
                 }else{
                     link = playlist.find("a")[corrente];
                 }
                 run($(link), musica[0]);
             });
         }
         
         
         function run(link, player) {
             player.src = link.attr("href");
             par = link.parent();
             par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
             player.load(); 
             player.play();
         }
```

```css
         ul{list-style: none; padding: 0px}
         a{text-decoration: none; color: #444; font-family: arial}
         li:hover{background: #eee; border-bottom: solid 1px #f60;}
         li{width: 20%; padding: 5px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;}
         .active a{color:#f60; padding-left: 1px; font-style: italic;}
```

```html
<audio id="musica" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="controls">
    <source src="Blackbear-doremi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    Desculpaaa, o áudio não é suportado pelo seu navegador :( 
</audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="Blackbear-doremi.mp3"> BlackBear - Do Re Mi</a></li>
        <li><a href="BMTH-Medicine.mp3"> Bring Me The Horizon - Medicine</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hozier-TakeMeToChurch.mp3"> Hozier - Take Me To Church</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenta retirar as tag `<a>` e coloca um `<span>`, só não esquece de mudar no js tbm !!
Ou tbm pode tentar usar a propriedade `target=_self`.

Comment: Então, acabei de testar retirar as tag <a> e substituir-las por <span>, mas não funcionou. Em relação a propriedade target=_self, devo coloca-la em que lugar? Desculpa a ignorância nesse assunto, é que nunca tinha feito um player de música e não conhecia essa propriedade kkkk é a minha primeira vez.

Comment: Coloca na tag a dai !

Comment: ainda não consegui resolver :/